# Read file names from a file and store file names and contents to another file with '|' as delimiter

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, terminal

How to read file names from a file and store file names and contents to another file with '|' as delimiter.

I have a file called Filenames.txt, which stores names of text files.

```
> Cat Filenames.txt
File1.txt
File2.txt
File3.txt

> Cat File1
This is content of File1

> Cat File2
This is content of File2

> Cat File3
This is content of File3
```

All these files Filenames.txt, File1.txt, File2.txt, File3.txt are stores in directory called TestDir.

My expected output as follows,
Generate a new file in the below format.

```
> Cat Outputfile.txt
File1|This is content of File1
File2|This is content of File2
File3|This is content of File3
```

I tried the below code and getting some error,

```
#!usr/bin/env bash
file=$(cat Filenames.txt)
y=$(pwd)
for line in $file
do
    x=$(cat "${line}")
   echo -e "${line}"|"${x}" >> Outputfile.txt
done
```

Getting below error,

```
$ bash Script.sh
cat: 'file1.txt'$'\r': No such file or directory
Script.sh: line 7: : command not found
cat: 'file2.txt'$'\r': No such file or directory
Script.sh: line 7: : command not found
Script.sh: line 7: This is content of File3: command not found
```

Current Output:

```
test1_file
|
test2_file
|
test3_file|
```

Note : I'm using Bash shell in Window machine

Please help.
Regards,
Sooraj

Comment: `$ bash Script.sh cat: 'file1.txt'$'\r'` your Filenames.txt has dos line endings. Remove them.

Comment: As the [tag:bash] tag you used instructs - "For shell scripts with syntax or other errors, please check them at https://shellcheck.net before posting them here.". The script in your question has some obvious errors that shellcheck would tell you about. See also https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001.

Comment: @EdMorton : Thank you for the quick response. Let me check

Comment: There's a mismatch between name of files from `Filenames.txt` and `File1` and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to remove `CRLF` windows line ending with:

```
dos2unix Filenames.txt
```

Then, what I would do:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

while IFS= read -r file; do
    echo "$file|$(< $file)"
done < Filenames.txt > Outputfile.txt
```

```
cat Outputfile.txt
```

```
File1.txt|This is content of File1
File2.txt|This is content of File2
File3.txt|This is content of File3
```

Your shebang `#!usr/bin/env bash` was wrong, missing leading `/` on `usr`.

My version is simplified, based on your code.

---

To parse a file line by line, don't use a `for loop`, read https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001

Comment: Quenot: Thank you Gilles, it worked perfectly! I converted the file and tried the code and it worked!

Comment: Sure 'it works' ^^

Answer (score 1):

After fixing the Windows line endings issue in `Filenames.txt` (see [Why does my tool output overwrite itself and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45772525/why-does-my-tool-output-overwrite-itself-and-how-do-i-fix-it)), try this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

while IFS= read -r line
do
    if [[ -f "$line" ]]; then
        printf '%s|' "$line"
        cat "$line"
    fi
done < Filenames.txt > Outputfile.txt
```

Comment: Thank you for the code. I tried the code, and the output appear in single line and I'm trying to fix your code. I tried the below code and worked. Thank you for helping me :)

Comment: Either you did something wrong when copy/pasting my code or your other files also have Windows line endings that are causing line wrapping (see the link I gave you) - fix those too.

Answer (score 1):

With Ruby:

```
ruby -e 'ARGV.each{|fn| puts "#{fn}|#{File.open(fn).read}"}' File{1..3}.txt
```

Or with Bash:

```
for fn in File{1..3}.txt; do
    printf "%s|%s\n" "$fn" "$(cat "$fn")"
done
```

Both print:

```
File1.txt|This is content of File1
File2.txt|This is content of File2
File3.txt|This is content of File3
```

Either can be redirected to the desired file with:

```
[Ruby or Bash] > outputfile.txt
```

---

If your files names are inside a file, you can do:

```
ruby -e '$<.read.split(/\R/).each{|fn| puts "#{fn}|#{File.open(fn).read}"}' files.txt >outputfile.txt
```

(In Ruby, the `\R` is universal and will work regardless of line endings...)

In Bash:

```
while IFS= read fn; do
    printf "%s|%s\n" "$fn" "$(< $fn)"
done  <files.txt > outputfile.txt
```

Comment: @dawg Thank you guys for the valuable instructions. I tried all the methods you guys posted. Worked!